# DrupalDateTime class not work

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, datetime

I try to use the `DrupalDateTime` class in my theme to show native date and time in custom format based on special TimeZone in my nodes.

According to [New Datetime API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1834108) `DrupalDateTime` should be used instead of the PHP `DateTime` class or to functions like `date()`, `gmdate()`, or `strtotime()`.

I am using the following code in a theme.

```php
function MyThemeName_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  $node_date = $variables['node']->getCreatedTime();
  $date = new DrupalDateTime($node_date, 'UTC');
  $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran'));
  $variables['date'] = $date->format('Y/m/d');
}
```

I get this error

> Exception: DateTime object not set. in Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus->__call() (line 308 of core\lib\Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus.php).

Comment: Are you passing $variables by reference? Can you paste the whole function? Are you printing it in the template file?

Comment: I just asked for those details.

Comment: If you can't provide details, people can't help you @MojtabaReyhani. We don't need the whole function, just a small, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem. The less information you provide, the less people can help you (it's why your questions aren't being answered at the moment; people want to help, but you're not giving them the chance to)

Comment: salam dadash, what you mean "date is shown in english language"? language?  you want see results in Jalalian ( shamsiye khodemon) ?  plz   clarify what you want  to we can help you.

Comment: I see,So what you want? you want see node published date in  Shamsi?

Comment: if you looking for best way you can write another module or port calendar systems module to drupal 8 :). and if you only want see node published  date in persian I have a solution for you.

Answer (score 3):

The code you are showing is wrong because [`DrupalDateTime::__construct()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Datetime!DrupalDateTime.php/function/DrupalDateTime%3A%3A__construct/8) is expecting a string, while you are passing an integer, which is what [`Node::getCreatedTime()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AgetCreatedTime/8) returns.

Instead of `DrupalDateTime::__construct()`, you should use `DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp()`.

```
$date = DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp($variables['node']->getCreatedTime(), 'UTC');
```

Since the static method also accept a `\DateTimeZone` object as second parameter, your code could be similar to the following one.

```
if (isset($variables['node'])) {
  $date = DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp($variables['node']->getCreatedTime(), new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran'));
  $variables['date'] = $date->format('Y/m/d');
}
```

Since you seem interested to get strings in a specific language, you should also set the language code.

```
if (isset($variables['node'])) {
  $date = DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp($variables['node']->getCreatedTime(), new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran'), ['langcode' => 'the language code for the language you need']);
  $variables['date'] = $date->format('Y/m/d');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to retrun date in Shamsi(jalalian) try to convert it with

```
 if (isset($variables['node'])) {
 $timestamp = strtotime($variables['node']->getCreatedTime()); 
 $format = 'Y/m/d';
 $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
 $date = new \IntlDateFormatter("fa_IR@calendar=persian", \IntlDateFormatter::FULL, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, $timezone, \IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL);
 $date->setPattern($format);
 $variables['jdate']  =  $date->format(intval($timestamp));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This is good solution but not impelement DrupalDateTime class.

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani you're welcome, I asked you I can suggest a way to convert node published date to shamsi with shamsi month name and ... .  be win